# Alert message not rotating in IOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am building an iPhone app which shows an alert message when a particular button is tapped. *Auto-rotaion* is in *ON* state. When i rotate my phone the whole app view as well as the alert message rotates in `iOS7` But, in `iOS8` views are rotated except alert message`

Comment: This is not a ios8 issue it work for me at all orientations....My alert also rotate with view... Pls check your code again ... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIAlertView` does not work properly in `iOS8` The, `iOS8` uses a new `UIAlertController` The given linked worked for my case.

## [Reference Link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the iOS not able to understand the multiple operation at a time .You can call the UIalertview with delay like .I have same issue with iOS8 this code is working fine for me.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

-(void)showAlert
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Your alert Title." message:@"Your alert Message." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but its not working for me. Can u suggest something else.

Comment: yeah but its not not in that view controller

Comment: I checked with my teammates ...its a single threaded system.... n sorry i can't share the code